# MSI - Uninstall gives "Unidentified Publisher"

Tags: windows-installer, uninstallation, authenticode

I have created an MSI installer using Visual Studio 2008. I then sign this with signtool.exe and my authenticode certificate.

On a Vista x64 test PC, when the MSI is run the expected dialog appears identifying my company as the publisher.

However, when the program is uninstalled from Add/Remove Programs, the yellow "Unidentified Publisher" dialog is shown.

Is there any way to have the uninstall process signed? Google isn't showing up anything useful.

Many thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 10):

[Know issue, fixed in Win7 (MSI 5.0)](http://blogs.msdn.com/heaths/archive/2009/02/02/changes-to-package-caching-in-windows-installer-5-0.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When you install an MSI the payload is stripped from it and the stripped MSI package is stashed locally, since this package is needed to drive the uninstall and repair process. Since the cached package has been modified, the checksums in the signature will be changed so that the signature is broken.

Comment: Strange, works fine for me on Windows 7 - the entire package including payload is cached to `%WinDir%\Installer`

Comment: Have you checked the digital signatures of the cached files? they all show up as broken. Also the behavior may depend on your UAC settings. On my DEV desktop where I have UAC set to not constantly nag me, uninstalling goes through OK. On my VMs with UAC set to 'anal' it does prompt on uninstallation.

Comment: Yup, digital signatures on files are still valid. I have UAC pushed as high as it will allow on my development machine so that I'll (hopefully) pick up these errors before being pushed to production.